# difference between strcmp and __strcmp_sse2_unaligned

Tags: c, linux, libc

I got a binary and found the `strcmp got` not linked to `libc strcmp` but `__strcmp_sse2_unaligned`, and I want to know the difference between them.

```
pwndbg> p strcmp
$2 = {<text gnu-indirect-function variable, no debug info>} 0x7fcc5e5fbcd0 <strcmp>
pwndbg> got

GOT protection: Partial RELRO | GOT functions: 44

[0x6260e0] strcmp@GLIBC_2.2.5 -> 0x7fcc5e611570 (__strcmp_sse2_unaligned) ◂— mov    eax, edi


pwndbg> disass 0x7fcc5e5fbcd0
Dump of assembler code for function strcmp:
   0x00007fcc5e5fbcd0 <+0>: mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rip+0x33a199]        # 0x7fcc5e935e70
   0x00007fcc5e5fbcd7 <+7>: lea    rax,[rip+0x15892]        # 0x7fcc5e611570 <__strcmp_sse2_unaligned>
   0x00007fcc5e5fbcde <+14>:    test   DWORD PTR [rdx+0xb0],0x10
   0x00007fcc5e5fbce8 <+24>:    jne    0x7fcc5e5fbd04 <strcmp+52>
   0x00007fcc5e5fbcea <+26>:    lea    rax,[rip+0xc48df]        # 0x7fcc5e6c05d0 <__strcmp_ssse3>
   0x00007fcc5e5fbcf1 <+33>:    test   DWORD PTR [rdx+0x80],0x200
   0x00007fcc5e5fbcfb <+43>:    jne    0x7fcc5e5fbd04 <strcmp+52>
   0x00007fcc5e5fbcfd <+45>:    lea    rax,[rip+0xc]        # 0x7fcc5e5fbd10 <__strcmp_sse2>
   0x00007fcc5e5fbd04 <+52>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Go through [This](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp.c.html) , [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2) and [This](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, `strcmp` is one of so called *indirect functions* (this is a GNU extension), see [GCC documentation on function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), the section on `ifunc`. When `libc.so` is being loaded, linker sees the `strcmp` symbol marked as indirect function:

```
$ nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.26.so | grep strcmp
0000000000093ad0 i strcmp
```

Then it calls the *resolver function* and resolves the `strcmp` symbol to the value returned by resolver. **On your machine**, it happened to be an SSE2 implementation.